# $_item->getProduct() doesn't work for Shipping Email

Tags: shipment-email

$_item->getProduct() is used on Order Confirmation emails to get the product instance.
This does not work on Shipment & Credit Memo emails.
How can the Product instance (Not the item) be retrieved here?

Comment: In which file you are trying to get product ?

Comment: It was in Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/shipmet/default.phtml
The solution is to use $_item->getOrderItem(). I belive this is the same for Shimpemt and Credit Memo email templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution for me was to use.

```
$_item->getOrderItem();
```

to get the item instance.
I then got the child items for configurables as such:

```
// Configurable Child Items
  foreach($_orderItem->getChildrenItems() as $orderItem){
    $productId = $orderItem->getId();
    $productName = $orderItem->getName();
    $productUrl = $orderItem->getProductUrl();
    $productSku = $orderItem->getSku();
  }
```

I didn't use nned to use getProduct(), that still returned null for some values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $_item->getOrderItem()->getProduct()

Tom